# Send/receive UK SMS via web api? What's a good reasonably priced service?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I'm googling for sms gateways and am seeing a few alternatives (eg http://txtlocal.co.uk).  I'm wondering what people here have used for this?  All we need is a service where

a) we set up an account with the service, with a mobile number

b) we send their api a recipient number and some text and they text it out from the above number

c) any incoming texts to that number get converted into web requests and sent to a url of our choosing.

Obviously i'm not expecting it to be free but are there any that just charge you for sending out texts and don't charge for receiving?  Or any others that have 'package' deals, eg "up to 5000 texts a month for £X" sort of thing?

Just wondering what other people have used.  cheers, max

Comment: BulkSMS looks good but did you investigate Text Local? It's not clear to me which one is better.

Comment: I ended up going with TxtLocal as it happens.  I can't remember why, sorry, it was 6 months ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [BulkSMS](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/).

You can send [messages by a simple HTTP call](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/docs/eapi/submission/send_sms/), including specifying the originating address (sender). Replies can be [routed to you via an HTTP call](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/docs/eapi/reception/http_push/) to your server. The are additional options, such as [dedicated incoming numbers](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/w/solutions_incoming.htm) which remain persistent to your account.

[Credits can be purchased in bulk](http://www.bulksms.co.uk/w/pricing.htm) and do not expire at the end of the month.

They also have developers that assist on SO :)

Disclaimer: I work for BulkSMS

Comment: Thanks ptomli - since asking this i've used bulksms on another site funnily enough and it's a good service :)  There's also a rails gem for it which make life a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many companies out there who provides the [bulk sms service in uk](https://www.mobtexting.com/international/sms-gateway-uk) but most of them are pretty high in price, I know 2 providers whu provides the excellent service at an affordable rate.

1. **Mobtexting**
2. **Fast2SMS**